# IE9 crashes with Google Maps embed

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-9, google-maps-embed

I need help with this. I embedded google maps in page with width="100%" and height="100%". Everything works fine except when using IE9, it crashes. Any solutions?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [sample map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html) from Google that creates a full page map that works fine in IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try setting the width with the view port meta tag, and make sure the html body and map div are all set to 100% height and 0 margin/padding.

Comment: Hi bweaver, thanks for the answer. I am trying to embed directions map in a page and my knowledge is not high in this. Is there simple way to achieve this? regards

Comment: Google has numerous examples for their API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/  Find the one you want and then view the source. The directions-simple.html should help you out.